# How to get the method summary of a class in JavaDocs in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

This looks pretty basic but I don't find a way to get it. When I do F1 on a class, the class documentation I get in IDE does not have method summary. No one ever found it useful? Basically I want to get up to constructor and method summary http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html.

Comment: Looks like "external documentation" is the only way Shift+F1

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is more useful to show you the information as you type the program based on context.

I see this as I type e.g.

```
MyClass c = new
```

At this point it will show me all the constructors which could be used.

For methods/fields

```
double d = c.
```

At this point I see all the methods which return a value or fields which can be cast to a double.

If I type

```
double d = c.a
```

I now see all the methods/fields which start with `a`

Once I see what I want, I can press `enter` to insert and `tab` to replace with the method/field I want.

I can cheat and type just the upper-case letters and it will assume that ABC means `.*A.*B.*C.*` and it can be a quicker way to find what I am looking for.

Comment: Ya. But I found it useful for the first time because I want to use the JavaAPI with other JVM languages like scala and clojure.

Comment: @Naresh You can see all the fields and methods which can be applied for your context.  You write the code which you know you want and it will show you everything you could use with that.  You don't want to be search through methods you can't use.

Comment: I agree. Right now the plugin (cursive) I use not matured enough to do that. So mean while I was just wondering if there is any way to get what I wanted.

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot you've been doing good job of sharing your knowledge for quite some time.

Comment: @Naresh thank you, 10K answers on Java takes a while.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows and click on a method or class, ctrl+Q will open its javadocs. On a Mac, I believe ctrl+J should work. I'm not sure whether those mappings are my own or the defaults.

To view or change the mappings, you can open IntelliJ's preferences and go to "Keymap" under the "IDE Settings" section in the pane on the left. You can search for "Quick Documentation" and change it to whatever you'd like!

Comment: yes thats correct. But that would show only class comments. Not the method summary of the class.